# iOS: Size classes not changing for different sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, size-classes

I am trying to build a UI for my app using the storyboard in xcode.

I have recently changed the look and would like to have things slightly different for iPad as to iPhone. For example I want the cell height to be one height on ipad and another on iphone, with each different size adversely affecting where the label within the cell is positioned etc.

The annoying thing is I got this all working on a xib, but using the storyboard, I will build everyhting how I want it in compact width regular height for iphone, then go and build the UI for ipad in regular width regular height. Then go back to check things out for iphone and it has completely adopted what I have done in the regular regular size class.

This is infuriating, it effectively is pointless in having the size class, I may aswell use any any size class, but I don't want to. Images included below gives you a good visual representation.

so here I have made the UI for iphone

[image: so here I have made the UI for iphone]

Then here is the ipad before and after I make changes
[image]

[image]

Then head back to regular regular (iphone) and you can see the size for the cell has changed
[image]

If I was to then change it back to how it was before, and the go to ipad I would be looking at the first ipad image i included above. So annoying, how can I get it to work with the different size classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use sizeclasses to change the height of tableviewcell.None of the tableviewcell's properties can be modified by the sizeclasses.

When you choose a label or anything else that can be modified by the size classes ,you would see an "installed" checkbox at the bottom of the attributes inspector.You can install or uninstall a label in different size classes.

But when you choose a tableviewcell or a tableviewcell's subview,you would not see this checkbox.It don't make sense a tableviewcell appear  in one size class but disappear in another.

You have to use tableView's delegate method to change the height of a tableView.

Comment: Ah okay I never knew this, is there anything else that is not affected by size classes like table views? thanks for the answer I will mark you up

Comment: @DomBryan  Apple don't point out which class is not affected by size classes.Instead , Apple documented that UIViews , Constraints,Fonts can be changed by size classes. You can see more at :   Size Classes Design Help https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1

Comment: It's not entirely correct that you can't use size classes to change a UITableViewCell's height. If you use autolayout and `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and have a view that sticks to the cell margins inside the cell, the height of the row will adjust based on the view inside the cell. And you can use size classes to adjust the view. Hence, row heights based on size classes. Hope this helps.